# Remove IAM user from group in terraform state file

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have an AWS IAM user and group managed by Terraform 12.5. I am trying to migrate management from one Terraform code base to another, but I can't disrupt the actual resources. I can remove the user from the state file with:

```
terraform state rm aws_iam_user.testuser
```

In addition to removing the user from the state file, I want to remove the user's group membership from the state file. But the user remains in the "aws_iam_group_membership" resource after the "aws_iam_user" resource has been removed.

I have tried several things to remove the user from the "aws_iam_group_membership" resource, but only get syntax errors.

I suspect that the resource instance address I am using is wrong or this is not possible using state rm.

I try things like:

```
terraform state rm aws_iam_group_membership.testgroup-group-membership.testuser

Error: Invalid address

  on  line 1:
  (source code not available)

Resource instance key must be given in square brackets.

or

terraform state rm aws_iam_group_membership.testgroup-group-membership[testuser]

Error: Index value required

  on  line 1:
  (source code not available)

Index brackets must contain either a literal number or a literal string.

or

terraform state rm aws_iam_group_membership.testgroup-group-membership[0]
No matching resource instances found.
```

It's not clear exactly what constitutes an instance of "aws_iam_group_membership". The state file shows this:

```
{
  "mode": "managed",
  "type": "aws_iam_group_membership",
  "name": "testgroup-group-membership",
  "provider": "provider.aws",
  "instances":
    {   
      "schema_version": 0,
      "attributes": {
        "group": "testgroup",
        "id": "testgroup-group-membership",
        "name": "testgroup-group-membership",
        "users": [
          "testuser",
          "testuser2",
          "testuser3"
        ]   
      },  
      "private": "foobar==",
      "depends_on": [
        "aws_iam_group.testgroup",
        "aws_iam_user.testuser",
        "aws_iam_user.testuser2",
        "aws_iam_user.testuser3"
      ]   
    }   
  ]
}
```

This is similar to what's in the state file for the user:

```
{
  "mode": "managed",
  "type": "aws_iam_user",
  "name": "testuser",
  "provider": "provider.aws",
  "instances": [
    {   
      "schema_version": 0,
      "attributes": {
        "arn": "arn:aws:iam::1111111111111:user/testuser",
        "force_destroy": null,
        "id": "testuser",
        "name": "testuser",
        "path": "/",
        "permissions_boundary": null,
        "tags": {}, 
        "unique_id": "AIDAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZS"
      },  
      "private": "foobar=="
    }   
  ]
},
```

"instances" contains things like "schema_version", "attributes", "private", "depends_on".

But for AWS IAM users I believe "testuser" is an instance of "aws_iam_user"? Or maybe not. Maybe you can't have multiple instances of an AWS IAM user like you can with servers?

That would make "testgroup-group-membership" an instance of "aws_iam_group_membership"?

That would mean that running the following would remove the entire list of users who are members of the group?

```
terraform state rm aws_iam_group_membership.testgroup-group-membership
```

Because the set of user members is an instance of "aws_iam_group_membership"? Users themselves aren't instances?

The question is, how do I remove a user from a group in a terraform state file while leaving the actual resources untouched?

I don't want to manually edit the state file for a variety of reasons. For one, it's stored in S3 with a DynamoDB hash lock. And every time I've tried to manually edit the state file, it's gone horribly wrong.

Comment: The data inside `attributes` is a representation of the remote object that the resource is representing, it's not generally necessary to edit it directly. If you've removed the user from the group outside of Terraform already then `terraform plan` should detect that automatically during its refresh step. If you _haven't_ removed it from the group outside of Terraform then you can remove it from your configuration and run `terraform apply` to make Terraform do that. Editing the `attributes` to disagree with the remote object is ineffective because the next Terraform refresh will just reset it.

Comment: The process I have been following is to remove resources from state file A, commenting the code that defines it in source tree A. Then moving the code to source tree B and importing the resource into state file B specifying source tree B in the --config= parameter. The primary constraint is that I don't want to touch the actual resource. Just want to move its management from source source tree/state file to another. So I can't trigger terraform to do anything by changing actual resources.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is mainly a problem with trying to do this in Bash or other shell where quotes and brackets are special characters need to be escaped, perhaps combined with the way Terraform CLI parses arguments.

This *should* work:

```
terraform state rm aws_iam_group_membership.testgroup-group-membership\[\"testuser\"\]
```

Notice that I'm escaping both the brackets and the quotes. There may be a "cleaner" way to do it with single quotes, but I fixed my issue with the above before I had a chance to try it:

```
terraform state rm 'aws_iam_group_membership.testgroup-group-membership["testuser"]'
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today at a Windows10-Client:

- escaping only the quotes worked fine for me

```
terraform state rm aws_iam_group_membership.testgroup-group-membership[\"testuser\"]
```